# Filtering RDD1 on the basis of RDD2

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

i have 2 RDDS in below format

```
RDD1     178,1
         156,1
          23,2
RDD2     
         34
         178
         156
```

now i want to filter rdd1 on the basis of value in rdd2 ie if 178 is present in rdd1 and also in rdd2 then it should return me those tuples from rdd1.

i have tried

```
val out = reversedl1.filter({ case(x,y) => x.contains(lines)})
```

where lines is my 2nd rdd and reversedl1 is first, but its not working

i also tried

```
val abce = reversedl1.subtractByKey(lines)
val defg = reversedl1.subtractByKey(abce)
```

This is also not working.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If RDD2 is small then you can also collect it to an Array and then run `RDD1.filter(x => arr.contains(x._1) )` where `arr = RDD2.collect`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `rdd2` to key value pairs and then join with `rdd1` on the keys:

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq((178, 1), (156, 1), (23, 2)))
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(34, 178, 156))

(rdd1.join(rdd2.distinct().map(k => (k, null)))           
// here create a dummy value to form a pair wise RDD so you can join
     .map{ case (k, (v1, v2)) => (k, v1) }         // drop the dummy value   
 ).collect
// res11: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((156,1), (178,1))
```